# Possessive of "it" when used as a noun to name itself

Tags: nouns, pronouns, possessives

When speaking of the word "it", "it" is a noun and can double as a pronoun for itself.

For example, I can say something like the following:

> It's first letter is an *i*. Its second letter is a *t*. It's spelling is
>   now complete because its spelling is quite simple. It's really quite simple.

Is that correct?

Comment: There is no “correct” possible here, only confusion. I therefore recommend against putting ever yourself — or your readership — in that position. Say instead: “The first letter of *it* is *i*.”

Comment: I see what you're tryng to say, but you need to use quote marks ("), _italics_, **bold**, or CAPS to set off the instances where you are using "it" meaning the word "it" itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rule for this pathological example. Aside from rewording, the best solution I can think is to italicize or otherwise use a different font from the body text for *it* and then use an apostrophe + s in the normal font.

> *It*'s first letter is *i*.

Answer (score -2):

> It's first letter

*beeeep*

**It's** is an abbreviation for **it is**, and they can always be substituted for one another.

> It is first letter is an i.

This is uncorrect English.

Comment: April's first letter is an A; first's first letter is an f, letter's first letter is an l, and it's first letter is an i. That's the way it's.